# PHP function cannot be called

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I will try to explain my problem in a simple way. My code looks like these.

A web page, systemView.php, has following code

```
<?php require_once 'Common_Function.php'; ?>
<head>
    <script src="jF.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
     <div id="one"> <?php A(); ?> </div>
     <div id="two">  </div>
</html>
```

Common_Function.php is

```
<?php
    include 'systemView_Function.php';
    include 'database.php';
?>
```

systemView.php has `A()` as well as `B()`

```
<?php
    function A() {
        D(); // a function in database.php
        //and show a few button on the page
    }
    function B($number) {
        D(); // a function in database.php
        //some codes to show something in the page
    }
    if (isset($_POST['B'])) { 
        B($_POST['B']); 
    }
?>
```

`A()` function will show some buttons on the page when called. When one of the buttons is clicked. `javascript` will then call `B()` by `ajax`. This function in `js` is

```
$(".abutton").click(function(){
    $("#two").empty();
    var number = parseInt($(this).text());
    $.ajax({
        url: "./systemView_Function.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"B": number},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {   
            $("#two").append(data);
        }
    });
})
```

Now the problem is when `D()` is not included in `B()`, the codes run successfully and shows something in `id="two"` `div`. However, if `D()` is included in `B()`, console in browser shows errors, and nothing in second div.

Comment: What are the errors in the console?

Comment: database.php isn't included in systemView.php is it?

Comment: @TZHX Chrome shows `POST http://localhost:8888/systemView_Function.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: do i need to include it, as `A()` runs successfully?

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that, because you don't reference database.php in your systemView.php page, PHP cannot find the D() function and so throws an error.

A() runs because it is called from a page that has it in scope (from CommonFunctions.php), but when B() is called -- being a new request -- it doesn't know what to look for.

Comment: i `include 'database.php'` in `B()` now, and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could be of some assistance. :)